# Get Field Values From WordPress Query

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I used the following code to run a wordpress query...
    //using the $thePost[ID], get the fees associated with this accommodation from within the post_meta table.

```
$post_meta_querystr = "
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->postsmeta
WHERE $wpdb->postsmeta.post_id = '$thePost[ID]'
";

$customPostMeta = $wpdb->get_results($post_meta_querystr);
```

The table has fields called "meta_key" and "meta_value". I'd like to know how I can use the value of any row in "meta_key" to get its corresponding value from the "meta_value" field?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use the [get_post_meta function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)?

Comment: Ah ha!... I had forgotten about this function. Thank you sir for preventing me from reinventing the wheel  :)